# bash - check if cPanel is installed on the server

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos

I have a little script in bash which checks if the server is a cPanel server

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "checking"
x=$(/usr/local/cpanel/cpanel -V)
if [ "$x" ]; then
        echo "yes"
else
        echo "no"
fi
```

This  works fine and gives the correct expected output. However, when run on non-cPanel servers, it also throws the following error:

`./testcpanel.sh: line 2: /usr/local/cpanel/cpanel: No such file or directory`
I would like to suppress this output.

I tried inserting `2>&1 /dev/null` in the variable declaration but that doesn't work. It always gives `yes` as the output irrespective of whether cPanel exists on not.

how do I go about suppressing the output? (OS's tested on - CentOS 6 and Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: +1 for [not using `which`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) to determine whether cpanel existed or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following line

```
x=$(/usr/local/cpanel/cpanel -V)
```

to

```
x=$(/usr/local/cpanel/cpanel -V 2>/dev/null)
```

Saying so would *supress* the error message (actually redirect it to `/dev/null`).

Additionally, say

```
if [ -z "$x" ]; then
```

instead.  Upon inserting `2>&1 /dev/null` in the variable declaration, you redirected `STDERR` to `STDOUT` and made the variable contain something like: `./testcpanel.sh: line 2: /usr/local/cpanel/cpanel: No such file or directory` due to which you received a `yes`.